# AWS CloudFormation template - dynamically add multiple instances of the same object

Tags: amazon-web-services, configuration, amazon-cloudformation

I'm trying to create a CloudFormation template that'll include a [ConfigurationAggregator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-config-configurationaggregator.html). In order to aggregate data from other regions, the same template file should also define an object (one or more) of [AggregationAuthorization](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-config-aggregationauthorization.html).

The thing is, I'd like to ask the user (when they apply the template) about which regions to authorize for this aggregator. Another option could be to authorize it for all the regions which are relevant/active for this account.

I couldn't find a way to achieve that - to make the template somehow dynamic, according to the user input (or to choose from a list of relevant regions).
Is that even possible, or I'm looking at the wrong approach/tools?

Answer (score 0):

I'd just do global, as regions you're not using won't generate many events.

If you want it regional something like this should work. Just define the parameters before running the template, I put them in a json file.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Parameters:
  ApplyToUsEast1:
    Description: Whether to create resource in US-East-1. Value "true" or "false".
    Type: String
  ApplyToUsWest1:
    Description: Whether to create resource in US-West-1. Value "true" or "false".
    Type: String

Conditions:
  ConditionUSEast1: !Equals [ !Ref ApplyToUsEast1, "true"]
  ConditionUSWest1: !Equals [ !Ref ApplyToUsWest1, "true"]

Resources: 
  AggregatorUSEast1:
    Condition: ConditionUSEast1
    Type: AWS::Config::AggregationAuthorization

  AggregatorUSWest1:
    Condition: ConditionUSWest1
    Type: AWS::Config::AggregationAuthorization
```

Parameters file

```
[
    {
        "ParameterKey": "ApplyToUsEast1",
        "ParameterValue": "true"
    },
    {
        "ParameterKey": "ApplyToUsWest1",
        "ParameterValue": "false"
    }
]
```

Run it like this

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name config --template-body file://config.yaml --parameters file://config.json
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I do it global? Couldn't find a sample / documentation for that

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you think you need an aggregator?

Comment: For now, my aim is to add some ConfigRules and then query about their status across all regions within the same account

Comment: The Config documentation is quite vague in this area. I looked at this in detail about six months ago. I'm not sure that you need an aggregator for a single account. You should have a read through best practices https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/aws-config-best-practices/ . I haven't tried to set up Config in a single AWS account in a while, I always work with multiple accounts and usually with Control Tower, and Control Tower sets many things up for you.